# WHERE can I change the notification email message for role assigments?

Tags: 6, ubercart

I'm using Ubercart 2 and Drupal 6 and I cannot find the place where I can change/customize the notification email that's sent out for new and/or expiring role assignments.

Here is the generic message:

> The role, member, you acquired by purchasing a product at our store has expired. Any special access or privileges that came with it are now gone. You can purchase it again by going to MY WEBSITE
>
> Thanks again,
>
> MY WEBSITE

I've looked under conditional actions, and while that helps me understand how and when emails are sent I cannot change the message text from there. Neither can I change the message text in `admin/store/settings/checkout/edit/messages`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per TR on the Ubercart forums:

"You may change this text under the Conditional Actions settings:
/admin/store/ca/uc_role_notify_revoke/edit/actions"

http://www.ubercart.org/forum/support/32739/where_can_i_change_notification_email_message_role_assigments#comment-70607